# What wmi counters can indicate port exhaustion

Tags: windows, networking, wmi

I'm currently investigating an issue in which we suspect port exhaustion from too many outgoing connections is a factor. I'd like  be able to identify when the server is at or near to port exhaustion, and it seems that there should be some wmi counter which will indicate this, although I don't know which

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the currently active connections count you could Powershell it:

```
$a=gwmi -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_TCPv4 |select ConnectionsEstablished

$a.ConnectionsEstablished
```

Note that there is also a ConnectionsActive in the same class which displays cumulative rather than current connection count. [Here is a class reference](http://library.wmifun.net/cimv2/win32_perfformatteddata_tcpip_tcpv4.html).

---

As detailed in [this MSDN blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx) there are two system tweaks you can use to increase the system tolerance when client port exhaustion is a threat:

[*Begin quote*]

**Increase the upper range of ephemeral ports that are dynamically allocated to client TCP/IP socket connections.**

1. Start Registry Editor.
2. Browse to, and then click the following key in the registry:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
   ```
3. On the `Edit` menu, click `New`, `DWORD Value`, and then add the following registry value to increase the number of ephemeral ports that can by dynamically allocated to clients:

*Value name* `MaxUserPort`

*Value data* `<Enter a decimal value between 5000 and 65534 here>`

*You must restart your computer for this change to take effect. Increasing the range of ephemeral ports used for client TCP/IP connections consumes Windows kernel memory. Do not increase the upper limit for this setting to a value higher than is required to accommodate client application socket connections so as to minimize unnecessary consumption of Windows kernel memory.*

**Reduce the client TCP/IP socket connection timeout value from the default value of 240 seconds**

1. Browse to, and then click the following key in the registry:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
   ```
2. On the `Edit` menu, click `New`, `DWORD Value`, and then add the following registry value to reduce the length of time that a connection stays in the `TIME_WAIT` state when the connection is being closed. While a connection is in the `TIME_WAIT` state, the socket pair cannot be reused:

*Value name* `TcpTimedWaitDelay`

*Value data* `<Enter a decimal value between 30 and 240 here>`

*You must restart your computer for this change to take effect. The valid range of this value is 30 through 300 (decimal). The default value is 240.*

[*End quote*]

Comment: Unfortunately Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_TCPv4 shows *cumulative* state transitions, not current socket status. See https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/6c2eb6de89bf446687dd7651ad40246fe2441672/cmd/scollector/collectors/network_windows.go#L354-L364 for reference.